# twitter4j TwitterStream onDirectMessage doesn't work

Tags: java, android, twitter, twitter4j

I have a service in Android that uses UserStreamListener to constantly check to see if the user has new tweets. It works perfectly in `onStatus(Status status),` but when I try and test it using `onDirectMessage(DirectMessage dm),` nothing displays.

I have the correct permissions (Read, Write and Access direct messages) enabled on the Twitter console.

```
    StatusListener listener = new UserStreamListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onDeletionNotice(StatusDeletionNotice arg0) 
        {               
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrubGeo(long arg0, long arg1) 
        {               
        }

        @Override
        public void onStallWarning(StallWarning arg0)
        {               
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatus(Status status)
        {
            User user = status.getUser(); 

            String screenName = user.getScreenName(); 
            String profileImage = user.getProfileImageURL();
            String text = status.getText(); 

            makeNotification(profileImage, screenName, text);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTrackLimitationNotice(int arg0) 
        {
        }

        @Override
        public void onException(Exception arg0) 
        {               
        }

        @Override
        public void onBlock(User arg0, User arg1) 
        {               
        }

        @Override
        public void onDeletionNotice(long arg0, long arg1)
        {               
        }

        @Override
        public void onDirectMessage(DirectMessage dm)
        {   
            Log.v("Info", "HELLO WORLD"); // nothing shows up here when I have a new DM
        }

        @Override
        public void onFavorite(User arg0, User arg1, Status arg2)
        {               
        }

        @Override
        public void onFollow(User arg0, User arg1) 
        {               
        }

        @Override
        public void onFriendList(long[] arg0)
        {               
        }

        @Override
        public void onUnblock(User arg0, User arg1) 
        {               
        }

        @Override
        public void onUnfavorite(User arg0, User arg1, Status arg2)
        {               
        }

        @Override
        public void onUserListCreation(User arg0, UserList arg1) 
        {               
        }

        @Override
        public void onUserListDeletion(User arg0, UserList arg1)
        {               
        }

        @Override
        public void onUserListMemberAddition(User arg0, User arg1, UserList arg2)
        {               
        }

        @Override
        public void onUserListMemberDeletion(User arg0, User arg1, UserList arg2) 
        {               
        }

        @Override
        public void onUserListSubscription(User arg0, User arg1, UserList arg2)
        {               
        }

        @Override
        public void onUserListUnsubscription(User arg0, User arg1, UserList arg2)
        {               
        }

        @Override
        public void onUserListUpdate(User arg0, UserList arg1)
        {               
        }

        @Override
        public void onUserProfileUpdate(User arg0) 
        {               
        }
    }; 

    twitterStream.addListener(listener);
    twitterStream.user();
```

Comment: Were you receiving status inside onStatus method. I am testing my application on 3G data and I have not received any status however I am getting call backs on onfollow events. Any help would be appreciated.